# AngularJS orderBy percentages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have a table with a column such that I am trying to sort these percentages, but they are not being sorted as expected even though I have tried `parseFloat` and a few other methods of making sure angularjs (using 1.5.0) would successfully order them.

```
[
    {percentage: 8.82}
    {percentage: 0.00}
    {percentage: 11.36}
    {percentage: 21.88}
    {percentage: 25.74}
    {percentage: 22.22}
]
```

The two following screenshots show the two orders in which the percentages are sorted.

[image]
[image]

```
 <tr ng-repeat="p in percentages|orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort">
    <td>{{p.percentage}}%</td>
 </tr>
```

`percentages` comes from my nodejs server, where I create a percentage and use the `toFixed(2)` function, which returns a String. But I have tried then using `parseFloat()` on the String (both before and after it coming back from the server).

`reverseSort` is a boolean value in my controller that gets set on clicking of the column name.

`orderByField` is a string value set in similar fashion to `reverseSort`.

For @Loren who asked for the server code that returned by JSON (it is Typescript):

```
        for(let row of rows){
            row.percentage= parseFloat(((row.prop1/ (row.prop2 + row.prop1))* 100).toFixed(2));
        }
```

Comment: does data coming from server is Array on `number`/ object with `percentage` property?

Comment: Can't reproduce in this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/wzo0n94I0tIFJMha2oJk?p=preview; are you sure you're `orderByField` is getting set to a string correctly? It must be equal to `"percentage"` exactly.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan just setup a watcher and was going to confirm they are exactly the same, but of course i was missing a letter... going to retest a few things and see if it works. if it works i will probably delete my question, as I do not believe SO considers grammar errors as valid programming questions. Thank you for pointing that out to me.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan , much closer now it is sorting lexicographically http://prntscr.com/duembp

Comment: I'm not sure what to say. The plunkr, which is essentially the same code as what's in your question, shows the data sorting numerically. If it's not doing that in your application, there's obviously something else going on in code that you're not showing us...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan , yeah now my issue is figuring out why using `parseFloat()` in the server and logging the response, it is still a string. and also tried `{{p.percentage | number}}%` in my html which does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

Using Angulars $filter('orderBy') you can sort by an objects property, in this case being the 'percentage'. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http, $window, $timeout, $filter) {
 $scope.percentages = [
  {percentage: 8.82}, 
  {percentage: 0.00}, 
  {percentage: 11.36}, 
  {percentage: 21.88}, 
  {percentage: 25.74}, 
  {percentage: 22.22}
 ];


 $scope.sort = function(click) {
  if(click == true) {
   $scope.percentages = $filter('orderBy')($scope.percentages, 'percentage');
  }
                else {
                        $scope.percentages = $filter('orderBy')($scope.percentages, 'percentage', true);
                }
 }

});
```

```css
.header:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<table class='SO' ng-init='clicked = false'>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th class='header' ng-click='clicked = !clicked; sort(clicked);'>Percentage Failed</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="data in percentages">
   <td>{{data.percentage}}</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but there is no explanation to this, and does not completely solve my problem. But thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

How are you running parseFloat?

What about using something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.percentages.length; i++) {
    $scope.percentages[i].percentage = 
        parseFloat($scope.percentages[i].percentage);
}
```

See:  https://plnkr.co/edit/cybPTR63KyCqzVT2bDRK?p=preview

I made your array strings beforehand since that is what you were getting from the server and then parse them into floats in JS.

You should run this code each time you fetch numbers from the server (ie after the first time and each subsequent time).  Also, make sure it runs after the results have been fetched (ie in the success callback) rather than right after the request since then it won't have any numbers yet.

Comment: yes this is what i did. i had to parse in my controller after it returned from the server.

Comment: But that isn't working? Or that is working and your trying to fix it serverside now?

Comment: it works client side, but if someone offers to a server side solution i am open to accepting it.

Comment: You will need to post a subset of your nodejs code for us to help with that.  Your question makes it sound like you couldn't get it working using client or server side parseFloat.

Comment: That is correct, let me update with a small chunk of server code. also included that server is written in ts.

Comment: Thanks, it looks good to me from the snippet so I'm not sure sorry.